# How to resolve ORA-12514, TNS:listener on k8s - oracle 12

Tags: java, spring, oracle, kubernetes

We have a simple 2 tier application and db.
I'm trying to deploy the java web application and oracle db in a k8s cluster.
The purpose for this deployment for Developers and testing environments.

**The problem:**
The application fails to connect to the oracle DB with the below stack trace
Both application and oracle db pods are deployed to the same namespace.

**Application layer spec:**

- application server: tomcat.9.0.22
- java vendor version: java.azul.8.33
- os: centos 7.6

**DB layer**

- Oracle: 12.2.0.11-ee

**Note:**

- Connectivity issues were dropped after I have installed a sqlplus client on the application container and managed to connect to the oracle db pod through sqlplus.
- I have managed to launch the application from my machine with the same container pointing to the DB inside the cluster, and the app started successfully.
- The same configuration was validated with container not running in the k8s cluster and successfully connected to the DB

Stack Trace:

```
WARN - Get connection from DB pool failed with following exception:
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
 )
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at com.foo.infrastructure.database.fooDataSource.getConnection(fooDataSource.java:59)
at com.foo.infrastructure.database.DataSourceFactoryBean.testConnection(DataSourceFactoryBean.java:261)
at com.foo.infrastructure.database.DataSourceFactoryBean.getObject(DataSourceFactoryBean.java:243)
at com.foo.infrastructure.database.DataSourceFactoryBean.getObject(DataSourceFactoryBean.java:27)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1646)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at com.foo.init.RCMContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(RCMContextLoaderListener.java:41)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:801)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:782)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
at com.jamonapi.proxy.JAMonDriver.connect(JAMonDriver.java:72)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
... 66 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:273)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:318)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1481)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:540)
... 74 more
Error during loading RCM DataSource. Unable to get connection from DBCP pool For more details check RCM log
ERROR - ***********************************************************************************
  Repository connection not correct
  ***********************************************************************************
ERROR - ****
ERROR - Spring failed to load.
oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocolNIO.negotiateConnection(NSProtocolNIO.java:273)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:318)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1481)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:540)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:782)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
at com.jamonapi.proxy.JAMonDriver.connect(JAMonDriver.java:72)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at com.foo.infrastructure.database.fooDataSource.getConnection(fooDataSource.java:59)
at com.foo.infrastructure.database.DataSourceFactoryBean.testConnection(DataSourceFactoryBean.java:261)
at com.foo.infrastructure.database.DataSourceFactoryBean.getObject(DataSourceFactoryBean.java:243)
at com.foo.infrastructure.database.DataSourceFactoryBean.getObject(DataSourceFactoryBean.java:27)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1646)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:551)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
at com.foo.init.RCMContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(RCMContextLoaderListener.java:41)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
ERROR - ****
01-Apr-2020 09:52:43.171 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
01-Apr-2020 09:52:43.173 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/RCM] startup failed due to previous errors
01-Apr-2020 09:52:43.198 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [RCM] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
01-Apr-2020 09:52:43.208 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-9.0.22/webapps/RCM] has finished in [9,734] ms
01-Apr-2020 09:52:43.213 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Apr-2020 09:52:43.220 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
01-Apr-2020 09:52:43.222 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [10,444] milliseconds
```

Comment: In the future, search for the [ORA ERROR](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/db92/db92.error_search?remark=homepage&prefill=ORA-) code on google first. Here that was `ORA-12505`. And the [first result](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-fix-ora-12505-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descriptor/).

Comment: Sorry just notice I have put a wrong stack trace. Hope this one make more sense.. Tried to check for the ORA-12514 but nothing really helped to resolve the issue. consider the tests I have made, "note" them

Comment: Go to the first result link, go to the bottom of the page. Use that to build your connection string. **NOTE** We cannot see your current connection string or your database configuration. **NOTE** All we can see is what you provide in the question.

Comment: Ok, I will add to the note that the same configuration with the same connection string was validated when running the same container not in k8s cluster

Comment: And yet the listener adapter (as documented [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-fix-ora-12505-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descriptor/)) cannot resolve the service. Your first exception and your new exception are all about the tns listener. You can bypass that. As documented in the link. Or you can keep adding notes here. Best of luck!

Comment: you are pointing to wrong error code. the first stack was really a mistake with the SID and the connection string , and by honest mistake I attached it here. so incase you can't answer that is fine. Just saying I am working with DBA as well, and they haven't help resolve that yet.

Comment: I am not. "TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor"; Oracle uses a TNS listener adapter to resolve service(s) to database SID(s). Your adapter is not correct for the image in your kubernetes cluster. Either fix your "tnsnames.ora" on every node, or bypass that and specify your connection string with the correct SID. Your DBA works with Oracle a lot? Because this should be elementary for an Oracle DBA.

Comment: Yes they are working with Oracle , I'll try to observe the connection string in logs exactly as the applications is using and will paste it here in case it helped. Thanks :)